# How to show Taxonomy menu on Page View?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I would like to show Taxonomy menu on Page view ,so i could select different taxonomy terms to show related items with it.It has to exactly like following  link www.techmusicschool.co.uk/courses/index.php

Answer (score 0):

I used Quick tab module to made taxonomy terms as tabs then i have created different views for each tabs and yes its working ...Thanks..